# How Can I Perform DML Operations insert,update,delete records of an Object Using JS(client-side controller) and Apex(server-side controler)

Tags: apex, soql, javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am very new in Salesforce, What i want is to have a complete explanation and code example in how to insert,update,delete multiple or single records of an object. Using Apex Server Side Controller Sqol Query and JS Client Side Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it via Salesforce AJAX Toolkit. The AJAX Toolkit is a JavaScript wrapper around the API. The AJAX Toolkit is available for any organization that has API access. Here is a example given [here](http://anuragsfdc.blogspot.com/2014/05/Insert-Records-SF-by-using-JavaScript.html). hope this helps.

**Code snippet from the example:**

```
<apex:page id="Page" sidebar="false">
    <script src="/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function insertAccount(){
            // Getting Session ID.
            sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

            //Creating New Account Record.
            var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
            //Getting Account Name from inputText.
            account.Name = document.getElementById("Page:Form:PB:PBS:PBSI:Name").value;

            // This is the line where magic happens, calling Create() method.
            var result = sforce.connection.create([account]);

            if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
                alert("New Account is created with id " + result[0].id);
            } else {
                alert("failed to create new Account " + result[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="Form">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Insert Account" tabStyle="Account" id="PB">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Name" columns="1" id="PBS">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="PBSI">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Name" />
                    <apex:inputText title="Name" id="Name" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton onclick="return insertAccount();" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is salesforce official guide for "[AJAX Toolkit Developer's Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_ajax.pdf)"

Comment: Hi, Saroj! This code fails when I try to run the VF page in one of the partner community.

Comment: Check the developer console, what JavaScript error you are getting. I think the issue may be related to Community user permission.

Comment: Thanks Saroj for the suggestion. I was able to debug and find that API Enabled permission was missing for the community user.

Comment: I tried in another community and I'm getting an error as 500, Site under maintainince. Do you know this error

Comment: Please check this link https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009sd2IAA. It is saying that Ajax toolkit does not work on communities and standalone force.com sites. Can you verify this with Salesforce? Please let me know I will add this information to the answer.

Comment: Saroj I collected some more information and found it is a bug from salesforce where this is not completely supported in communities. I tested this as well I created two communities and the same user was granted access to both communities and it worked in one and not in the other, Unfortunately where I wanted it to work it didn't worked.

Comment: Nishant better to create a ticket with Salesforce and get more details.